# Starting Lightdm display manager: [FAIL]

Tags: boot, lightdm

[image: a busy cat]

How do i solve this?

It maybe related to my previous problems:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/588685/booting-to-black-screen-ubuntu-14-04-2/588698#588698

[System Settings Missing/Bluetooth Settings/Sound Settings/Programs Missing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588334/system-settings-missing-bluetooth-settings-sound-settings-programs-missing/588344#588344)